# nant tasks to copy zip folder from one machine to other

Tags: nant, task

How do i copy a zip folder from my local machine to a server on same domain using nant script

Answer (score 2):

Use the [nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/copy.html) copy task.

```
<copy 
    file="myfile.zip"
    tofile="\\servername\folder\myfile.zip"
    inputencoding="latin1"
    outputencoding="utf-8" />
```